# Using ACF date picker to only show posts after today's date

Tags: wordpress, datepicker

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to create a post-type called 'Events', and the jquery date picker to select the date of the event. I currently have the posts ordered by event date, started with the earliest date to the latest, however I want past dates to not show up in the query.

Here is my code:

```
            <?

            if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
              $paged = get_query_var('paged');
              } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                      $paged = get_query_var('page');
              } else {
                      $paged = 1;
              }
              query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'meta_key' => 'event_date', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged ) );
              while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?>
```

So basically, if the event date is past the current date, I don't want the post to show anymore.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a custom query:

```
global $wpdb;
$items_per_page = 10;
$offset = 0;
        $query = "
            SELECT
                posts.*,
                DATE(postmeta.meta_value)
            FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts AS posts
            RIGHT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta AS postmeta ON (postmeta.post_id = posts.ID)
            WHERE
                posts.post_type = 'events' AND
                postmeta.meta_key = 'event_date' AND
                postmeta.meta_value > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:00') . "'
            ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value ASC
            LIMIT " . $offset . ", " . $items_per_page . "
        ";

$events = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    foreach ($events as $event): setup_postdata($event);
              //event loop

    endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Where `date('Y-m-d H:i:00')` is your current date format